# Checklist for releasing an open source library

Tags: open-source, release

I have been working on a web development library (for the CodeIgniter framework) that I soon hope to release.

This would be my first contribution ever, and I have never released an open source library in the past.

I wanted to appeal to the experience of some of you for any steps to follow before releasing. I know that testing and documentation are key... what else ?

Comment: When you look at other libraries, what do you see offered for support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Licensing...........
2. Packaging (e.g. source tarball, Debian repostory etc.)
3. Discussion Group
4. Issue tracker
5. News feed ( for releases, project announcements etc. )
6. Roadmap
7. List of known "bugs"
8. Features List
9. List of non-goals
10. Demo site
11. Example usage

Of course you can release something with much less... it comes down to how much "appeal" you want your project to gather in the public.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your code is clearly commented, anything thing that was trival to implement attempts documented.

Answer (score 0):

To add to jdupont's list,

Documentation - many OS projects become popular simply because they have better documentation
(If Applicable)  Short Video of major features, or a series of short videos showing off different features.  That's frequently the first thing I look at. If don't have time for it, at least some sreenshots so people can get a sense of how things are interacting.